# Microphone produces humming noise

Tags: laptop, audio, microphone

I have bought new headset and the headphones are working correctly, but if I connect the mic it produces **low frequency humming noise**. The microphone is connected using 3.5 jack. The noise is not white noise, more like bumblebee in trashcan. If I turn of input amplification the noise is quitter, but still there. It almost sounds like if you turn volume to maximum on TV, but the there is no audio signal, the repros just humm.

When I connect the microphone, the Windows recognize it has been plugged in and the driver does too. The laptop has built-in mic and while the external microphone was plugged in the system actually recorded the sound from the built-in mic.

In the Sound control panel there is only *one recording device* visible.

I then connected borrowed microphone and everything was okay. The sound was clear, and the built-in microphone was not recording.

To me it seems, the system is unable to recognize the external mic properly and mixing the input from the built-in with the external mic. I have tried on 2 different notebooks and the result was still same. New mic produces noise and the built-in don't shut off, borrowed works fine.

**Does this mean the new mic is broken?**

Comment: OT question, how are these headsets (assuming headphones with mic) powered? Headphones can have powered amps in them for volume range, and microphones can be a powered type or a non-powered type. If this is a powered type, then it is likely to be a noisey power driver curcuit in them, either cross talking with the mic, or poorly powering the mic element as a powered mic. Is it broken? you said it worked , records sounds?  IF it is properly connecting , because a mic not fully connected can also humm/buzz. There is some issue you do not like? send it back.

Comment: It has no external power, it's powered only through the jack. Also I will send it back, but I want to figure out the issue to avoid it next time.